# How to correlate (X,Y) coordinate pairs in one meaningful unit

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, face-detection

I have a 2D Array, where each row is a feature vector.
Each feature vector is like: [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4] where, (x1,y1) are coordinates of first feature point, (x2, y2) of second feature point and so on...

I need to give the feature points as input to a neural network. Now, how do I combine x1 and y1 into one meaningful unit before feeding it into neural network? I am stuck here...could anyone please suggest what to do?
I read somewhere we have to use some two-dimensional transformation...like SVD...but I can#t figure out how actually???

I am working with C++ and OpenCV 2.3

Any help would be very much appreciated...thanks!!!

Comment: You typically don't. Each of those elements of the feature vector is passed as an input to the neural network. Combining them into a single input will lose some information. For example, if you only cared about the distance from the origin, you could calculate the euclidean distance to each pointer, but then you've lost information about orientation.

Comment: @sftrabbit actually we do...i read a paper by S.N. Kohail on "Age Estimation using facial images and ANN". On page 3, 1st paragrapdh...its mentioned to group the coordinates into one meaningful unit first....it has also been mentioned in other papers...

Comment: even in case of struct....lets say i create an object "feature" and i store coordinates as: feature.x and feature.y
still i need to combine the two...
@VaughnCato

Comment: What is a "meaningful unit"?

Comment: i mean...the neurl network has to know the feature location...i have to give that location as (x,y)...giving individual x and y would make no sense.... @VaughnCato

Comment: @user2346085 It depends. If there is some correlation between the values of `x` and `y`, then sure, you could encode that in some way. But if they're just two values that can vary independently, then they are just two separate inputs to the network. Your network will still learn properly without knowing that these two values are related in your problem domain.

Comment: would it work properly? are you sure? @sftrabbit

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the basic requirement a data structure to correlate between (x1,y1) with (x2,y2) and so on.
In that case,you may use std::pair along with std::vector.You may check the following example for reference.

```
std::pair<double,double> firstCoordinate,secondCoordinate;
std::pair<std::pair<double,double>,std::pair<double,double> > coordinateMap;
std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<double,double>,std::pair<double,double> > > coordinateMapVector;
```

In the above example firstCoordinate and secondCoordinate are (x1,y1)  and (x2,y2) respectively,which can be mapped using coordinateMap.And coordinateMapVector will be having set of all such mapping between two coordinate systems.

Also the above share data structure can be updated by something like following mentioned.

```
firstCoordinate  = std::make_pair(1.0,1.0);
secondCoordinate = std::make_pair(2.0,2.0);
coordinateMap    = std::make_pair(firstCoordinate,secondCoordinate);
coordinateMapVector.push_back(coordinateMap);
```